# How to add captcha to Typo3 FORM cObj?

Tags: forms, typo3, captcha

According to the official form extension documentation, there is a CAPTCHA FormObject:

> This object will search for an installed captcha extension and use it
>   at the position where it is put in the form. This can be on top, but
>   also at the bottom of the form. Currently all (correct me if I'm wrong
>   here) captcha extensions are supported.

However, I wasn't able to use it in my form. There is not captcha item in the form wizard, even if I explicitly add it to the PageTS config. When I manually try to add a captcha to my form, nothing happens.

Did anybody succeed adding a captcha to a form built using the (not so) new form extension?

Comment: Which captcha extension do you have installed?

Comment: Ok, and which T3 version? (Sorry)

Comment: Latest version, in 4.7 serie (4.7.10)

Comment: Have you included the static template? http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/sr_freecap/2.0.0/view/3/1/

Comment: In TYPO3 V 6.2 are two different form extensions. Default is a very simple Version. You have activate the sysext "form" and included the static template to used the advanced extension. If there is a CAPTCHA intergration I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a captcha, I recommend installing https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/wt_spamshield. This extensions supports the old and the new form extension of TYPO3 up to 6.2. This extensions adds different, invisible form protections which are more powerful than the unreadable captchas ;)

IMHO the new form extension (EXT:form) does not support any captcha extension.